# Best way to define a 2D lookup in excel using lambdas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm surprised that Excel still doesn't have a simple function `2D_LOOKUP(array, row, col)`.  For instance, I have a complicated excel sheet I'm managing and I frequently want to pull the value for a given parameter on a given date.

As a specific example, I want to turn:

|  | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | A | B | C | D |
| Row2 | E | F | G | H |
| Row3 | I | J | K | L |

And call `2D_LOOKUP(Array, Row2, Date2)` and get back `F`.

However, thanks to `lambda` I can now define such a function.  There are various ways to do it - using `XLOOKUP`, using `INDEX` and `MATCH`, using `VLOOKUP` etc.

I am curious what is the most optimal way to do it.  The code itself could be complicated, since my plan is to just define it in the name manager via a `LAMBDA` and forget about it from here on out.

I saw https://medium.com/@gareth.stretton/excel-matrix-lookup-with-lambda-30a345472152 which seemed to have an excellent solution, but it used `MAKEARRAY` and I wasn't sure how efficient that was.

To be clear, I'm looking for a complete solution - I want code that I (and subsequent readers) can simply drop straight into the Name Manager.

Thank you!
/YGA

Comment: Why not use `Double XLOOKUP()` or `Double FILTER()` function?

Comment: Also you cannot have a defined name that starts with a number it has to be an `underscore` or `some different names`

Comment: The name matters less to me.  I don't love using a double xlookup because I'm perpetually trying to remember exactly how to get it right and I lose time in the debugging.  The whole point of functions is that you don't have to deal with that.

Comment: Name your rows and columns with the row/column headers, and use the `Intersection` operator with the `INDIRECT` function.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` is already a 2D lookup function, just substitute the match function for the `col_index_num`

Comment: You can obviously use **`Intersection`** operator with `INDIRECT()` function using defined name with `LAMBDA()` as well, but one drawback is `INDIRECT()` function is `VOLATILE` in nature and it will recalculate everytime whenever there is a change in any open workbook. However, this is the `LAMBDA()` version named as `INTERSECT()` --> `=LAMBDA(Row,Col, INDIRECT(Row&"_") INDIRECT(Col))` and use as `=INTERSECT(A7,A8)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way without using any `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C8</kbd>

```
=_2D_LOOKUP(A1:E4,A7,A8)
```

---

Where `_2D_LOOKUP()` is defined name in name manager, and refers to the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(Array,Row,Col,
 LET(
     _Data, Array,
     _Array, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     _Row, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1),
     _Col, DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1),
     XLOOKUP(Row,_Row,XLOOKUP(Col,_Col,_Array,""),"")))
```

---

The custom `LAMBDA()` function with its arguments as

[image]

---

```
=_2D_LOOKUP(Array, Row, Col)
```

---

[image]

---

**Excel naming rules**

When defining a name in name manager, one should follow these basic rules:

• A Name should be under **`255 characters long`**.

• Names can't contain **`spaces`** and most **`punctuation characters`**.

• A Name must begin with a **`letter`**, **`underscore (_)`**, or **`backslash (\)`**.
If a name begins with anything else, Excel will throw an error.

• Excel names are **`case-insensitive`**.

• One cannot **`cell references`** like `MAT1` or `SSS1` to a range.

• One can use a single letter to name a range like `a`, `b`, `D`, etc. except for the letters `r`, `R`, `c`, and `C` (because these characters are used as shortcuts for selecting a row or column for the currently selected cell when you type them in the `NameBox`).

---

Naming Guidelines taken from **[here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-named-range/)**

---

Comment: Cool!  I like a lot.

Is there a way to do a "bakeoff" to determine which is the most efficient?

Comment: @YGA obviously this will be more efficient because it doesn't involves any `LAMBDA()` helper functions within the defined `LAMBDA()` function.

Comment: I believe you but perhaps other folks might end up providing other solutions and it would be nice to see which was fastest!

Comment: @YGA surely, why not, but the fact is a double `LAMBDA()` helper or a single `LAMBDA()` helper function will be slow in respect to using the one I have given! You should test on your own!

Comment: For instance - this uses XLOOKUP.  Would an INDEX MATCH be faster than XLOOKUP?

Comment: Nope, `XLOOKUP()` is much faster than any `Lookup` functions till date!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this version is faster or slower, but it certainly does a better job of dealing with erroneous data.

```
=LAMBDA(Array,Row,Col,
LET(ACol, MATCH(Col, TAKE(Array, 1), 0),
    ARow, MATCH(Row, TAKE(Array, ,1), 0),
    IFERROR(INDEX(Array, ARow, ACol), "")))
```

Another version with `VLOOKUP` function (a bit shorter):

```
=LAMBDA(Array,Row,Col,
 LET(ACol, MATCH(Col, TAKE(Array, 1), 0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Row, Array, ACol, FALSE), "")))
```